# Battery Protection IC With NTC Thermistor

Tags: microcontroller, power, lipo

I have a battery design which is failing EN 62368-1 for thermal cut-off on charging conditions.  IE. at the maximum temperature, charging currents need to cut off at maximum temperature.

I am looking at a battery protection IC with an NTC thermistor:

https://www.batteryspace.com/prod-specs/5080%20spec.pdf

Is the design intent that you run the thermistor output (it's a voltage divider with another resistor?) to an ADC on a microcontroller to determine the temperature and have some kind of shut-off FETs to the charging input?

Comment: My suggestion is to not use that protection circuit. Or, call battery space and ask. If they are unable to answer, find something else. Choose an IC from a manufacturer who publishes a real datasheet. Maybe the protection circuit has an NTC on it. Or maybe you are supposed to wire the NTC from the T terminal to P-. Who knows?

Comment: Totally agree. I'm just trying to see if someone has wired this sort of thing up in the past and can weigh in on what I should "reasonably" expect.

I didn't even know, but TDK makes chip thermistors (and it looks the chip thermistor can cut out voltage in a divider by itself to a microcontroller -- I wonder if you can bolt that into a protection IC on a battery board and that would work).

https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/protection/temperature/chip-ntc-thermistor/technote/apn-chip-ntc-thermistor.html#tablets

Comment: Every three-wire protection circuit I have seen put the thermistor between the T pin and GND. The responsibility for driving and sensing was on the charge circuitry. The protection circuit did not have independent over-temp protection. The charge circuit was supposed to implement that function. These were consumer products with single cell non-removeable lithium polymer battery packs.

Comment: Looking at the picture, it seems there is a component with silkscreen label "T" that may not be installed (in the picture). This is probably the thermistor. You can probably test out the connection visually or with an ohm-meter if you buy one of the protection circuits.

Comment: Cheers, thanks!  I'm looking at some Microchip charge ICs and am seeing the same thing.  Problem is... the charger IC in this case doesn't have the thermistor sensing ability.  I'm looking at like a TCO but the temps are way above the 45C limits.  I'm like kind of thinking of how you could built a new protection IC board on the battery with some independent thermal cutoff at like 35C.  I'm going to ping TI on BQ2980 as there is some notes in the datasheet about internal die temp. sensing independent of a thermistor.

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/t/900770

Comment: You just need one comparator 3 resistors and the NTC thermistor to implement an over-temp cutoff. Double check if you also need under-temp cutoff (I think you do). So you may need two comparators and a few more resistors. The NTC thermistor needs to be in close thermal communication with the battery cell.

Comment: Clever!  I'm not really up to steam on all the semiconductor solutions out in the world! Notes for future: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa02/snoaa02.pdf?ts=1588083699877 && http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa995a/snoa995a.pdf?ts=1588083920691

Comment: I had the same issue with a PCM circuit that had provisions for a Thermistor that was not populated. The T terminal should be the output from the Thermistor, and then ground (P-) is the other. I was lucky to already have a fuel gauge on the main board besides the battery charger IC (which BTW did not have a temperature measurement input). There are TI devices that will include some analogue means for temperature detection, or as some others suggested, using a dual comparator IC with hysteresis to determine upper and lower cut-off temperatures which I assume will be 45° C and 10° C. ..

Comment: Generally speaking your battery pack is not failing the En 62368, it is rather your application circuit that makes use of the battery pack that does not have provisions for over/under-temperature cut-off. Most battery pack suppliers only provide PCM circuits with MOSFETS and pretty much all ICs doing this over/under-voltage and/or current protection do pretty much the same thing whether from TDK, or Microchip or Diode Inc or whatever. ..

Comment: The over-under-temp monitoring is the battery pack user's responsibility, and this may involve more or less elaborate schemes for implementing. It may involve simple comparator to trigger interrupt on micro, which then stops charging, or it may simply turn off charger directly when temp limits are reached (the later not requiring having a micro actually actively monitoring the battery charging)...